# GeoServer GetLegendGraphic for multiple layers

Tags: geoserver, getlegendgraphic

Can I get legend with multiple layers using GetLegendGraphic on GeoServer?

It works fine for 1 layer and suppose to work for layer group according to this documentation https://www.geosolutionsgroup.com/blog/developers-corner-geoserver-getlegendgraphic-enhancements/ but I am getting an error that layer does not exist if I add name of layer group.

```
http://geoservername/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=testgroup
```

Are there some specific settings for the layer group that I need to add?

Answer (score 2):

The default GeoServer data directory comes with a couple of configured layer groups. I had a test with the "spearfish" group.

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetLegendGraphic&layer=spearfish&format=image/png

It seems to be possible to get a legend for a layer group.
I noticed that you used WMS version 1.0.0 in the request. GeoServer does not support it, but it seems that with this request it does not care. I also noticed that &WIDTH and &HEIGHT behave in some odd way with a layer group. However, you have not managed to get so far yet. I suggest to compare your layer group configuration with the GeoServer demo layer group.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your idea helped to resolve my issue.  I had problem with the assigned workspace name in my layer group. But I didn't include it is the link.